# Symfony / Doctrine - sorting with QueryBuilder

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, query-builder

This is my scenario:
I have User entity associated 1-n with Post entity. Now I want to list specified users sorted by certain criteria - one of them is user's posts number. 
In SQL it would be something like this (it works on my database):

```
SELECT user.*, COUNT(post.id) AS posts 
FROM user LEFT JOIN post ON user.id = post.author_id 
GROUP BY user.id ORDER BY posts DESC
```

And my QueryBuilder (fragment):

```
$query->leftJoin('u.'.$sort, 'p')
      ->select('u, count(p.id) as '.$sort)
      ->groupBy('u.id')
      ->orderBy($sort, 'DESC');
```

Variable $sort accepts specified sort criteria like 'posts' in my scenario. Then, $query->getQuery() is returned by my method to controller and used by paginator (before adding new sort criteria like above it works). From logical point of view, this should work. However, Symfony throws an exception "Key "id" for array with keys "0, posts" does not exist." in my view, specifically in this place:

```
<a href="{{ path('user', {'user': user.id}) }}">
```

My question is, how to construct this QueryBuilder properly? If there is need of additional code to show, let me know. Thanks.

Comment: try access your query result in 0 index, like $results = $queryResult[0];
then pass $results

Comment: I just changed user to user[0] in my view, but your solution is basically the same. Thank you very much.